# Magento Commerce - Use new image type on front page

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I added a new image type to the image uploads called featured_banner_image.  If a product is marked as featured I have a jQuery slider that will pull the featured_banner_image on the front page.

The problem is that

`<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'featured_banner_image')->resize(135) ?>">`

does not work.  What code can I pull to grab my new image?

Comment: It would be very useful if you could update your question by adding such informations as for ex.: how did you add new image type.

Comment: I added an attribute for the banner image.  I mentioned in my post it is a new image type.  I have Base, Small Image, Thumbnail and now I have Featured Banner Image in my list of image choices.

Comment: if you added new image type to your product using attributes, then it should work like a charm...

I've presume that you have launched reindex before adding new image to product ?

Do you have any errors in magenta/apache logs ?